# React-redux: Why can't I access state properties in a class component, when it works in a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm pretty new to React and Redux, so I don't know what is causing the errors when I try to access properties in a class component through props vs. when I access them through arguments in a functional component.

#### Actions

```
import { FETCH_TOPMOVIES_SUCCESS,FETCH_TOPMOVIES_FAILURE,SELECT_MOVIE} from "./movieTypes";
import axios from "axios";

export const fetchTopMoviesSuccess = movies => {
    return {
        type: FETCH_TOPMOVIES_SUCCESS,
        payload: movies
    }
}

export const fetchTopMoviesFailure = error => {
    return {
        type: FETCH_TOPMOVIES_FAILURE,
        payload: error
    }
}

export const selectMovie = (movie) => {
    console.log('selected movie: ' + movie.title)
    return{
        type: SELECT_MOVIE,
        payload: movie
    }
}

export const fetchTopMovies = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        axios.get(api)
        .then(response => {
            const movies = response.data.results
            dispatch(fetchTopMoviesSuccess(movies))
            console.log('this is the response result:')
            console.log(response.data.results)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            const errorMsg = error.message
            dispatch(fetchTopMoviesFailure(errorMsg))
            console.log('this is the errror message:')
            console.log(errorMsg)
        })
    }
}
```

#### Reducers

```
import { FETCH_TOPMOVIES_FAILURE, FETCH_TOPMOVIES_SUCCESS, SELECT_MOVIE } from "./movieTypes"

const initialState = {
    selectedMovie: null,
    movies: [],
    error: ''
}

export const moviesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_TOPMOVIES_SUCCESS:
            console.log('returned successful request')
            return {
                movies: action.payload,
                error: '',
                selectedMovie: null
            }
        case FETCH_TOPMOVIES_FAILURE:
            console.log('error when fetching from the api')
            return {
                ...state,
                movies: [],
                error: action.payload
            }
        default: return state
    }
}

export const selectedMovieReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SELECT_MOVIE:
            return {
                ...state,
                selectedMovie: action.payload
            }
        default: return state
    }
}
```

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { moviesReducer, selectedMovieReducer } from "./movie/movieReducer";


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    movies: moviesReducer,
    selectedMovie: selectedMovieReducer
    
})

export default rootReducer
```

#### Store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import rootReducer from "./rootReducer";

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))

export default store
```

#### App

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MovieList from './Components/MovieList';
import store from './redux/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import NewMovieList from './Components/NewMovieList';

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div className="App">
        <NewMovieList/>
        <MovieList/>
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now, the functional component, **NewMovieList**, works as intended. It displays the list of movies and there are no errors.
It looks like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './MovieList.css';
import Movie from './Movie';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchTopMovies } from '../redux';

function NewMovieList({ movies, fetchTopMovies }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchTopMovies()
    }, [])
    return movies.error ? (
        <h2>{movies.error}</h2>
    ) : (
        <div>
            <h2>Movies:</h2>
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='moviegroup'>
                    <ul>
                        {
                            movies && movies.movies && movies.movies.map(movie => <Movie key={movie.id} movie={movie}></Movie>)
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        movies: state.movies
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchTopMovies: () => dispatch(fetchTopMovies())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NewMovieList)
```

However, the class component, **MovieList**, does not work. I get "Uncaught TypeError: this.props.movies.map is not a function" and have previosly gotten other errors, like "cannot read property of undefined" etc.
The component looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './MovieList.css';
import Movie from './Movie';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchTopMovies } from '../redux';

class MovieList extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('component did mount')
        this.props.fetchTopMovies()
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        console.log(this.props.movies)
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='moviegroup'>
                    <ul className='movies'>
                        {
                            this.props.movies.map(movie => <Movie key={movie.id} movie={movie}></Movie>)
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        movies: state.movies
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchTopMovies: () => dispatch(fetchTopMovies())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MovieList);
```

It seems to me that the class component cannot read the state, even though I connected it through mapDispatchToProps, but I'm not sure and I don't know how to get it working.
I really want to understand how to work with both types of components, so can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Your code between the two different components is not the same.

Both of them grab `state.movies` out of the Redux store. That's fine.

Per the reducer, `state.movies` is an object like `{ selectedMovie: null, movies: [], error: '' }`.  That means that within the component, the array you care about is `movies.movies`.

The function component checks `movies && movies.movies && movies.movies.map`.  So, it's correctly accessing the nested array.  (btw, the `movies && movies.movies` part is unnecessary, because `state.movies.movies` is *always* an array - you initialized it that way!).

However, the *class* component isn't doing that.  It's just doing `props.movies.map()`.... except that `props.movies` is the *object* like `{selectedMovie, movies, error}`.  So, you'd need to do `this.props.movies.movies.map()`.

Having said that, I'm afraid that the style of Redux code you're writing is very outdated, in multiple ways:

- You're "hand-writing" Redux reducers and action creators
- You're using `connect`
- You're using class components

Today, we teach "modern Redux" with Redux Toolkit and the React-Redux hooks API, which is much simpler to learn and use.  The code you're writing will *run*, but it's going to require writing at least 4x as much code, and will be more confusing.

I'd strongly recommend reading through our official Redux docs tutorials, which teach Redux Toolkit and React-Redux hooks as the standard approach:

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index